# Regular Expression Pattern Metadtata

Tags: java, regex

I would like to inspect a regular expression to identify the matching groups that it contains. The following is an example of the kind of API I would like to have:

```
String pattern = "^My name is \"([^\"]*)\" and I am (\d*) years old$"
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern)

Group g1 = p.getGroups(0); // Representing the name group
g1.getStartPosition(); // should yeild position in regex string, e.g. 14
g1.getEndPosition();   // 21

Group g2 = p.getGroups(1); // Representing the age group
g2.getStartPosition(); // 34
g2.getEndPosition();   // 39
```

This is not offered by the java-standard `java.util.regex.Pattern`, but I wondered if there were any existing open-source libraries that would allow me to inspect regular expressions in this way?

I would rather avoid having to roll-my-own, attempting to pick-apart the regex string with the `java.lang.String` API, as that would be particularly cumbersome.

Comment: first of all your string is not valid i contains more than two "

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Are you trying to write a regex tester?

Comment: [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) (accessible via `Pattern.matcher("input string")`) does provide the api you require (`groupCount()`, `start(group)` and `end(group)`), but it applies to the `"input string"`, not the regex. But, coming up with a regex to match groups isn't that easy.. (recursion, excluding `(?:` etc...)

Answer (score 0):

This is not professional API, but I encourage you to try this class out. I made it as a exercise, It has couple methods similar to `Matcher`, like: `group(int group)`, `start(int group)`, `end(int group)` or `groupCount()`. It is rather easy to use.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Metamatcher {
    private String pattern;
    private TreeMap<Integer,Integer> groupsIndices;

    Metamatcher(String pattern){
        this.pattern = pattern;
        groupsIndices = getGroups();
    }
    /**
     * @param group ordinal number of group
     * @return starting index of a fragment of pattern, which contain group capturing
     */
    public int start(int group){
        ArrayList<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>(groupsIndices.keySet());
        indices.add(0,0);
        return indices.get(group);
    }

    /**
     * @param group ordinal number of group
     * @return ending index of a fragment of pattern, which contain group capturing
     */
    public int end(int group){
        ArrayList<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>(groupsIndices.values());
        indices.add(0,pattern.length());
        return indices.get(group);
    }

    /**
     * @param group ordinal number of group
     * @return String object containing fragment of regular expression which capture given group
     */
    public String group(int group){
        return pattern.substring(start(group), end(group));
    }

    /**
     * @return number of capturing groups within given regular expression
     */
    public int groupCount(){
        return groupsIndices.size();
    }

    public String toString(){
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        result.append("Groups count: ")
                .append(groupCount())
                .append("\n");
        for(int i = 0; i <= groupCount(); i++){
            result.append("group(")
                    .append(i).append(") ")
                    .append(start(i))
                    .append("-")
                    .append(end(i))
                    .append("\t")
                    .append(group(i))
                    .append("\n");
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    /**It extracts fragments of regular expression enclosed by parentheses, checks if these are capturing type,
     * and put start and end indices into Map object
     * @return Map contains fragments of regular expression which capture groups
     */
    private TreeMap<Integer,Integer> getGroups(){
        String copy = pattern;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\([^\\(\\)]+\\)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(copy);
        TreeMap<Integer,Integer> temp = new TreeMap<Integer,Integer>();

        while(matcher.find()){
            if(isCapturingGroup(matcher.group(0))){
                temp.put(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
            }
            copy = copy.substring(0,matcher.start()) + replaceWithSpaces(matcher.group(0)) + copy.substring(matcher.end());
            matcher = pattern.matcher(copy);
        }

        return temp;
    }

    /**
     * @param fragment of regular expression, enclosed by brackets
     * @return true if given String consist regular expression which capture groups
     */
    private boolean isCapturingGroup(String fragment){
        return fragment.matches("((?<!\\\\)\\((?!\\?<?[:=!])[^\\(\\)]+\\))");
    }

    /**
     * Provide a filler String composed of spaces, to replace part enclosed by brackets
     * @param part String containing starting and ending with brackets,
     * @return String composed of spaces (' '), with length of part object,
     */
    private String replaceWithSpaces(String part){
        String filler = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < part.length(); i++){
            filler += " ";
        }
        return filler;
    }
}
```

I tested it with variuos input and compare output with tools like regex101 and it works for me.